# input type text doesn't work in ipad iOS 7

Tags: html, css, ipad, safari

I have the following input which belongs to a form:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" required>
```

When I access the page from an iPad, I can not input anything into the text input. The keyboard does not show up so I can't type. How can I fix this? If using a textarea longer works, this is weird ..

Comment: As your `name="phone"` attribute tells that you want numbers to be entered so Have you tried `<input type="number"/>`?

Comment: no, but I have another that takes text input

Answer (score 0):

Try below code may be work fine..

```
<input type="text" name="phone" required />
```